# .Net Core backend API response will only come back when each calls are finished (users are waiting for each other's requests...)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, backend

I have seen a strange behaviour in one of our services and I have no idea about the possible root cause.

When I call a backend API like 20 times at the same time, I will got the response back at the same time from the 20 calls... it means if only 1 call is there it will finish within a second if 20 is used those will finish within 8 seconds.

I have made some logging in the controller and saw that the first ok response were sent before the 6. was started, but even in this case I got back the response at the same time as others.

Do you have any idea what might be the problem with the backend service?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any locks in your service?

Comment: What type of database are you using?  It sound like you are not using a database that is designed for multi-users.  Excel and Access are not designed for multi-users and often behave similar to what you are seeing.

Comment: There is no any locks and I'm using elastic as DB. But I think both are unrelated for the current topic, since my problem is that I would expect to get back the response as soon as I send back an ok response.

The first "return new OkObjectResult(result)" was called even before all the calls are started, but still did not got back the response from backend until all of them were finished.

Comment: Can you post some code to go along with this, maybe your controller or methods it implements?